# Task Scheduler Laravel 5.4 cron not automatically running Mac OSx

Tags: macos, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-5.4

I'll cut straight to it. My Task Scheduler is not running automatically with a cron job and only works if I run:

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

All I am doing in the `handle()` function is:

`\Log::info('scheduler running @' . \Carbon\Carbon::now() );`

This runs perfect and logs when the command is run so I know there is nothing wrong with my `artisan` command but the the cron job itself, or something within my configuration of my localhost.

I have tried two methods for the `crontab` entry.

`* * * * * php Sites/projectname/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

```
* * * * * cd Sites/projectname; php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Neither are working and I should get a log every minute as in `app/Kernel.php` in the `schedule()` function I have this code. `$schedule->command('send:email')->everyMinute();`

I have tried clearing the Laravel cache with `php artisan cache:clear` I have tried restarting my Laravel server and I have restarted my apache server with `sudo apachectl restart`

Can any hero save the day?

Thanks

Comment: use `php -q` instead `php` and tell me if worked

Comment: @MortaddaJafar This is the output in the mail file. PHP Parse error:  parse error, expecting &' or variable (T_VARIABLE) /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 444

Comment: this happened because you use PHP version doesn't support the splat operator ..

Comment: run `which php` and copy output to your commend for example your output `/usr/local/bin/php` corn job commend will be : ` ... /usr/local/bin/php  -q ...`

Comment: @MortaddaJafar absolute hero, works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED**

@MortaddaJafar sorted the issue for me so the credit goes all to him.

Basically my Laravel php version was `5.6.4` and my apache php server version was `5.6.30` so what this did was cause a compatibility issue as my PHP version didn't support the splat operator. placing `-q` into my cron `php -q` allowed me to debug the issue as an error message gets sent out to `/var/mail/nick`.

To solve this issue just apply the direct path to your php version to run the cron, this avoids version issues. Run `which php` to get the path and then add this into your cron.

```
* * * * * cd Sites/projectname; /usr/local/bin/php -q artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Hope this helps someone facing similar issues.

Nick.